# EF Self many-to-many with additional parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Person model with many-to-many relations to Person:

For example:

```
public Person()
{
    ICollection<Person> Management {get;set;}
    ICollection<Person> Staff {get;set;}
}
```

Each manager may have many related workers, and each worker may have many related managers.

So I also have a connection table:

```
public class PersonLinks
{
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    public MyTypeEnum/or maybe int/ RelationshipType { get;set; } 
}
```

Also Fluent API code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(m => m.Staff).WithMany().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapLeftKey("StaffId");
    m.MapRightKey("ManagerId");
    m.ToTable("PersonLinks");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(m => m.Management).WithMany().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapLeftKey("ManagerId");
    m.MapRightKey("StaffId");
    m.ToTable("PersonLinks");
});
```

This works well, but I want to also map "MyTypeEnum Relationship" property to the Person model, so can I do this:

```
myPerson.Management.Add(new Person{RelationshipType = ...})
```

Or:

```
myPerson.Staff.FirstOrDefault().RelationshipType = ...
```

Comment: To do that you're going to need to map the junction table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have additional columns in the junction table you need to map it as part of your model and create two one to many relationships:

```
// Configure the primary key for the PersonLinks
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonLinks>() 
    .HasKey(t => new{t.ManagerId,t.StaffId });

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonLinks>() 
    .HasRequired() 
    .WithMany(t => t.Management) 
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ManagerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonLinks>() 
    .HasRequired() 
    .WithMany(t => t.Staff) 
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.StaffId);
```

And your person entity would be

```
public Person()
{
    // other properties
    ICollection<PersonLinks> Management {get;set;}
    ICollection<PersonLinks> Staff {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can add it as you are trying to do:

```
myPerson.Management.Add(new PersonLinks{RelationshipType = ...});
```

Comment: It is ok, but I want to avoid ICollection<PersonLinks> properties in model and work only with persons.

Comment: I"m afraid  there is not another way :(